# TeeChart C# Points series custom width

Tags: c#, teechart

The TeeChart Points series has the GetPointerStyle event can be used to change the color and the style of each point of the series, but there is a way to change the width property of each point of the series?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GetPointerStyle` to modify the Series' `HorizSize` and `VertSize` properties. Ie:

```
private void Points1_GetPointerStyle(CustomPoint series, GetPointerStyleEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ValueIndex % 4 == 0)
  {
    series.Pointer.HorizSize = 4;
    series.Pointer.VertSize = 4;
  }
  else
  {
    series.Pointer.HorizSize = 2;
    series.Pointer.VertSize = 2;
  }
}
```